# How to run a script in administrator mode with commands to execute

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator, chocolatey

I would like, from a powershell script, launch another powershell instance in administrator mode and, if possible, indicate to it some code to be executed in this same command line.

Here is the concrete case (*I am using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) for my package management under windows*) :

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "choco outdated"
```

This code works, but unfortunately the powershell window closes immediately after executing the code. So it is "impossible" to see outdated packages.

Do you have a solution for either:

- freeze the script after the command?
- or add more line of code to put `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10`?
- or another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Read-Host` will interrupt and wait for user input

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed I tried this: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "choco outdated","Read-Host" ` and this: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "choco outdated Read-Host"` unfortunately it does not work, after displaying outdated packages the window closes!

Comment: You can try this: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit choco outdated"`

Comment: It works perfectly too! Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get it to wait.

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "choco outdated`n`rpause"
```

Comment: Oh perfect! This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'NoExit' argument:
[About PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

```
PowerShell[.exe]
    [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo]
    [-NoExit]
    [-Sta]
    [-Mta]
    [-NoProfile]
    [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>]
    [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File - | <filePath> <args>]
    [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command - | { <script-block> [-args <arg-array>] }
                | { <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?
```

Be sure to put the arguments in the '-ArgumentList' parameter in the correct order.

```powershell
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-noprofile", "-command choco outdated"
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add several commands at the end? like this : `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-noprofile", "-command choco outdated", "-command choco upgrade"`